# Facebook and some other websites show me their mobile versions

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, opera, mobile-url

My user agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.517

Facebook and some other websites show me their mobile versions. This started to happen all of a sudden several weeks ago and in all browsers i.e. FF, Chrome, Opera! I use Opera most of the time.

My zoom is at 100%, never changed it.

It's an old desktop: Windows 7 Professional 32, ATI Radeon Xpress 1100, Dell Optiplex, Intel Pentium R

[image]

Comment: Since you're on older hardware/software, is your desktop or browser window size in the range that might "trick" a responsive site into thinking it needs the mobile version? Some responsive designs are based on size rather than the easily spoofed user agent. For layout that can be nice, but a real PITA when it pops over to other mobile-related features too.

Comment: @Gypsy Spellweaver I also thought of that but the thing is that my desktop is hooked up to a 32in Samsung TV. I just don't understand why all of a sudden I have this problem while it's been fine for 3 years up to now.

Comment: Final "shot-in-the-dark" ideas. 1)Do those sites have a profile that might have synced to your mobile device (if you use one)? 2) Do you use some kind of sync/cloud service with those sites, or your browsers? 3) Do you go to the sites with bookmarks, or direct typing? 4) Are all these rouge sites connected somehow, and sharing one set of user data?  5) Try this sequence: Actively log out of the website; removed the saved data for the site (if any), including passwords; clear out cookies. Repeat for the other browsers. __Then__ restart _one_ browser and check it.

Comment: Thanks. They are unrelated websites like Tutorials point and others. I suspect it is to do with Bootstrap